# How find bigger image from image url by any image search engine (google ? )

Tags: java, google-image-search

I am lurking around is there any way

1. search image by image url
2. get results with images which theirs image_size is medium/big(one option, hardcoded)
3. list items and select first one

Probably the easiest way would be using google search engine. So far I managed to take my custom image url and use in google search engine "search image by image url".

This the image

```
http://107.6.170.83/~nooboard/2img/3076.jpg
```

and this is the standard google url query

```
https://www.google.pl/searchbyimage?image_url=http%3A%2F%2F107.6.170.83%2F%7Enooboard%2F2img%2F3076.jpg
```

I know I can use in search engine phrases like `imagesize:500x500` but it doesn't work in url. Also I don't know what is phrase for setting general image size like small, big, medium or icon.

How could I modify my url to go automaticaly to google images and get result images with specific general size?
Probably If I get there it would be easy to parse first image by JSOUP and get url of this item.

Any suggestion in any language would be great, but the main code language is JAVA. ( I will update topic if I find any solution).

Comment: Did you try to use GDATA api?

Comment: I am not sure if GDATA could search image by image url and retrieve bigger images

Comment: You are not sure, but you did not checked it?

Comment: I am checking now and I don't see solution :)